# Como capturar uma query no MySQL de uma determinada tabela em tempo real?

Tags: mysql, query

Estou querendo capturar as consultas que são enviadas ao MySQL de uma determinada aplicação, é possível?

Comment: Legal teria algum exemplo que possa ser utilizado?

Comment: @MarcosVinicius Acho que você entendeu errado a pergunta.

Answer (score 3):

Se você tiver a versão paga, existe o [**Enterprise Monitor**](http://www.mysql.com/products/enterprise/monitor.html).

Na versão "pobre", você pode ativar o [**General Log**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-log.html), mas não é possível ativar ou desativar por banco de dados.

Com o log ativo, você tem a opção de desligar e ligar novamente dinamicamente com os comandos:

```
SET GLOBAL general_log = 'OFF';
```

E...

```
SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON';
```

Comment: Opa, Obrigado. Vou testar.