# Como visualizar consultas que retornaram erro?

Tags: mysql, vba, debug

Olá,

Gostaria de saber se no mySQL, no prórpio dicionário dele (MySQL) consigo fazer um debug das query que retornam com erro de uma determinada aplicação que seja?

Comment: Você está usando PHP? Explique melhor sua dúvida por favor.

Comment: Não, VBA e preciso visualizar se alguns erros que retornam é no banco ou na aplicação (que é quase certo que seja a aplicação) mas preciso de informações especificas que comprovem.

Comment: você já pesquisou sobre os log de erros do mysql? http://ftp.nchu.edu.tw/MySQL/doc/refman/4.1/pt/error-log.html

Comment: Não seria basicamente o que você já perguntou em http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/37778/como-capturar-uma-query-no-mysql-de-uma-determinada-tabela-em-tempo-real?

Comment: Acabou que ficou parecido, mas na verdade não sei o mysql trata de queries com  erros juntos com as todas as consultas. Vou da uma analisada da documentação do mySQL se encontro que pode ajudar nessa questão de log. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Rodrigo, não seria melhor adicionar um tratamento de erros no código?

Comment: Farei isso! Obrigado.